# Memory allocation optimization: from heap to stack

Tags: c, optimization, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory

I am doing some reverse engineering tasks towards binaries on `32-bit x86` architecture.

Recently I found some interesting optimizations from `C` source code to assembly program.

For example, the original source code is like (this source code is from `openssl library`):

```
powerbufFree = (unsigned char *)malloc(powerbufLen);
```

And after compilation (`gcc version 4.8.4 -O3`), the assembly code is like this:

```
807eaa0: cmp eax, 0xbff                         # eax holds the length of the buf.
807eaa5: mov dword ptr [ebp-0x68], eax          # store the length of powerbuf on the stack
807eaa8: jnle 0x807ec60                         # 0x807ec60 refers to the malloc
807eaae: mov edx, eax
807eab0: add eax, 0x5e
807eab3: and eax, 0xfffffff0
807eab6: sub esp, eax
807eab8: lea eax, ptr [esp+0x23]
807eabc: and eax, 0xffffffc0
807eabf: add eax, 0x40
807ead3: mov dword ptr [ebp-0x60], eax  # store the base addr of the buf on the stack.
```

**To my surprise, the buf is indeed allocated on the stack!!!** It seems like an optimization for heap allocator for me, but I am not sure.

So here is my question, does the above optimization (malloc --> stack allocation) seems familar to anyone? Does it make sense? Could anyone provide some manual/specification on such optimization?

Comment: where is the malloc call?\

Comment: This reminds me very much of Escape Analysis in newer JVMs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis

If the memory will never live outside of the function call, it may be safely allocated from the stack. If you have the space in your stack this will be a much faster alloc/free pair of operations.

Comment: I think heap is a general tree structure. By traversing the heap with Depth FIrst Search method, the elements visited in sequence from the order of a stack.

Comment: @self, please see my comments on the third line of the assembly code.

Comment: @VikranthInti. Thank you for your reply. I am asking about an "optimization" that directly allocate memory on the memory stack when it is supposed to allocate on heap.

Comment: @user3629249 how is that relevant to his question? answer: it's not.

Comment: @sam. Thank you for your reply. This is a very reasonable inference. This optimization could be due to an escape analysis.

Comment: @self ,  Simple, I was not answering the question, I was commenting on a bad practice that was being used in the posted code.  Please understand that answers to questions are in the blocks below and comments are to help the OP to produce better code.

Comment: @user3629249. Hi, thank you for pointing out. 1) I copy/paste partially from openssl source code. 2) In their original code, they have a checking routine for the (!=NULL).

Comment: All I can find is https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2013-01/msg00084.html, which claims that gcc does indeed perform this optimization.

Comment: @melpomene You should post that as an answer.

Comment: I tried it with `gcc-4.8.5 -O3` `gcc-4.9.3 -O3` `gcc-5.4 -O3` `gcc-6 -O3`: the call to malloc is still here.

Comment: @melpomene: Follow the responses to the message to https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2013-01/msg00087.html, where it states it is not optimized yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [source of bn_exp.c:](http://osxr.org:8080/openssl/source/crypto/bn/bn_exp.c#0578)

```
0634 #ifdef alloca
0635     if (powerbufLen < 3072)
0636         powerbufFree = alloca(powerbufLen+MOD_EXP_CTIME_MIN_CACHE_LINE_WIDTH);
0637     else
0638 #endif
0639     if ((powerbufFree=(unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(powerbufLen+MOD_EXP_CTIME_MIN_CACHE_LINE_WIDTH)) == NULL)
0640         goto err;
```

Note that `0xbff` is equal to 3071. On systems that support it, `alloca` does stack allocation. This is true of the [GNU version](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variable-Size-Automatic.html#Variable-Size-Automatic), which is used by [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca), and [BSD implementations](http://www.retro11.de/ouxr/43bsd/usr/man/cat3/alloca.0.html) copied this API from 32V UNIX from AT&T ([according to FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=alloca&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%206.1-RELEASE&format=html)).

You only looked at line 639. But if `alloca` is defined, then the C code matches up to your assembly.

The optimization itself is often used to avoid the expense of using `malloc` for a temporary buffer if the allocation is relatively small. For C.1999, a VLA could be used instead (since C.2011, VLA is an optional feature).

Sometimes, the optimization just uses a fixed size buffer of some reasonable smallish size. For example:

```
char tmp_buf[1024];
char *tmp = tmp_buf;

if (bytes_needed > 1024) {
    tmp = malloc(bytes_needed);
}
/* ... */
if (tmp != tmp_buf) {
    free(tmp);
}
```